# How to read multi layer php object

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

I get the following data from a webhook:

```
{
  "id": 1,                                           
  "date_created": "2017-08-31T11:26:38.000Z",        
  "date_approved": "2017-08-31T11:26:38.000Z",       
  "date_last_updated": "2017-08-31T11:26:38.000Z",   
  "money_release_date": "2017-09-14T11:26:38.000Z", 
  "payment_method_id": "account_money",     
  "payment_type_id": "credit_card",     
  "status": "approved",
  "status_detail": "accredited",
  "currency_id": "BRL",         
  "description": "Pago Pizza",  
  "collector_id": 2,            
  "payer": {                        
    "id": 123,                      
    "email": "afriend@gmail.com",   
    "identification": {
      "type": "DNI",                
      "number": 12345678            
    },
    "type": "customer"              
  },
  "metadata": {},
  "additional_info": {},
  "transaction_amount": 250,        
  "transaction_amount_refunded": 0,     
  "coupon_amount": 0,                   
  "transaction_details": {
    "net_received_amount": 250,
    "total_paid_amount": 250,   
    "overpaid_amount": 0,       
    "installment_amount": 250   
  },
  "installments": 1,            
  "card": {}
}
```

I get this data from the following expression:

```
 $payment = null;
 $payment = MercadoPago\Payment::find_by_id($_GET["data_id"]);
```

And I access the data as below:

```
 $pStatus = $payment->status;
 $payID   = $payment->id;
```

But I still did not figure out how to access the nested values as for instance, the email.
I tried to convert the object to an array as in:

```
$responseArray = $payment->toArray();
```

So I could access the email using:

```
$responseArray['payer']['email']
```

But not working...

I need to read all nested values.
Assistance welcome.

Comment: `$responseArray` is a misnomer if your response isn't actually an array. Have you tried `$responseArray->payer->email` ?

Comment: Not working = nothing been returned.

Comment: $responseArray->payer->email returns nothing. $payment->status returns valid data but $payment->payer->email returns what I need. Thanks